# XLDateAmbiguous error even when using dayfirst argument

Tags: datetime, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to import data into a pandas dataframe object from an excel spreadsheet parsing dates. I'm using `dayfirst` however I still get an error `XLDateAmbiguous` ([docs](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function))

The dates are in a single column in the format 25/09/1990

Could somebody explain to me why this happening and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Edit: It seems as though the problem is caused by xlrd attempting to parse a non-date column as a date even thought I've specified which column the dates are in. Unfortunately I don't know how to explicitly indicate that a column should not be parsed as dates. Does anybody have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

path6 = 'C:\\Users\\Site2_Homepage_2013-06-04.xlsx'
df8 = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path6, 'Site2_Homepage_2012_06_13', header=1, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)

XLDateAmbiguous                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-4a83d104ab72> in <module>()
      4 path7 = 'C:\\Users\\Site4_Homepage_2013-06-04.xlsx'
      5 path8 = 'C:\\Users\\Site7_Homepage_2013-06-04.xlsx'
----> 6 df8 = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path6, 'Site2_Homepage_2012_06_13', header=1, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
      7 df9 = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path7, 'Site4_Homepage_2012_06_13', header=1, parse_dates=[3], dayfirst=True)
      8 df10 = pd.io.excel.read_excel(path8, 'Site7_Homepage_2012_06_13', header=1, parse_dates=[3], dayfirst=True)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in read_excel(io, sheetname, **kwds)
    101     engine = kwds.pop('engine', None)
    102 
--> 103     return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)
    104 
    105 

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in parse(self, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands, chunksize, convert_float, has_index_names, **kwds)
    206                                  skip_footer=skip_footer,
    207                                  convert_float=convert_float,
--> 208                                  **kwds)
    209 
    210     def _should_parse(self, i, parse_cols):

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.pyc in _parse_excel(self, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col, has_index_names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands, chunksize, convert_float, **kwds)
    267                 if parse_cols is None or should_parse[j]:
    268                     if typ == XL_CELL_DATE:
--> 269                         dt = xldate_as_tuple(value, datemode)
    270                         # how to produce this first case?
    271                         if dt[0] < datetime.MINYEAR:  # pragma: no cover

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.pyc in xldate_as_tuple(xldate, datemode)
     78 
     79     if xldays < 61 and datemode == 0:
---> 80         raise XLDateAmbiguous(xldate)
     81 
     82     jdn = xldays + _JDN_delta[datemode]

XLDateAmbiguous: 15.3
```

Comment: Can you show the entire error/stacktrace. Sometimes I find it easier just to export to csv...

Comment: @AndyHayden I added the complete stack trace. Do you mean that I should convert the .xlsx to a .csv?

Comment: Looks like there is number (15.3) in the column you're trying to parse as dates ?

Comment: @AndyHayden I didn't realise that that was the value that was throwing the error. I've checked the sheet that the only time 15.3 appears is in the 5th column. So I'm completely stumped as to why that column is being parsed as a date column.

Comment: @Bprodz Because dates in Excel are stored as floats - See the library author's explanation under the header [Dates in Excel spreadsheets](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) and check out [xldate_as_tuple](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#xldate.xldate_as_tuple-function) which goes into further detail... It may be that `pandas` isn't utilising `datemode` correctly hence the exception... but I'm not that familiar with the `pandas` codebase...

Comment: @AndyHayden I did some experimenting by parsing less columns, it seems when I include the 5th column this problem occurs. I tried changing the format in excel of the columns to 'number' instead of 'general' but the problem still persists.

I also tried changing `parse_dates` to `False` and removing the other date arguments but the problem still persists so long as the 5th column is being imported. I think I'm about out of ideas, I'll update if I manage to find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonClements I read the sections that you're referring to and then tried changing some parameters (I even changed `parse_dates` to `False`)

The reason why I'm baffled is that I have several other excel files which are (seemingly) similar yet they are correctly imported into a `pandas` dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a solution of this. In the end I had to use `.csv` versions of the files for the dates to parse correctly.